# EMR Cluster terminates when trying to start a cluster with 2 nodes

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, cluster-computing, emr

I am using the following command to create a cluster on Amazon EMR:

```
*./elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --num-instances 1 --instance-type m1.medium --name "CLUSTER_NAME" --hive-interactive --hive-versions 0.13 --hive-site s3://mybucket/hive-site.xml --ami-version 3.3 --subnet subnet-mysubnetid*
```

Afer a few minutes, I can run Hive and everything goes fine. However, when I try to start a cluster with two nodes as the following code:

```
*./elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --num-instances 2 --master-instance-type m1.medium  --slave-instance-type m1.medium --name "CLUSTER_NAME" --hive-interactive --hive-versions 0.13 --hive-site s3://mybucket/hive-site.xml --ami-version 3.3 --subnet subnet-mysubnetid*
```

The cluster does not finish to set up. After 50 minutes approximately the cluster terminates.

I found the error log

```
xxx.xxx.0.28:40908 Call#2 Retry#0: error: java.io.IOException: File /mnt/var/em/verify-hdfs-access-1147553264033 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.

java.io.IOException: File /mnt/var/em/verify-hdfs-access-1147553264033 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2694)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
```

I understand that the cluster cannot create any DataNode and maybe there is something wrong with the configuration. Nevertheless, when I configure a single-node cluster everything goes fine. I have read a lot of stuff but I am a little lost at this point. Hope anyone could help or give me a clue abour the problem.

Tnanks in advance,

Pablo

Comment: The error is related to replication of data between nodes. This suggests that the nodes are failing to communicate with each other. Check that your nodes are being assigned a security group that allows them to communicate with each other.

Comment: Your problem seems to be caused by subnet settings, master can't communicate with the core node. Do you really need to specify subnet?